# Best way (best performance) to lock file creation

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a web application to return images to my frontend.
In this application what happens is: when a request is made to a particular image the application checks if the image already exists on disk; if it exists the image is returned.

My problem starts when the image does not exist on disk. In that case two requests are made at the same time for the same image which does not exist on disk. Problem occurs when two threads try to create the same file on disk at the same time.

To solve the problem, what I tried to do was to create a Mutex in the creation of disk image. But it had a problem: as the server load is enormous due to the large number of simultaneous requests, the server crashes.

I would like to ask what your ideas to solve this problem. Or what you would do otherwise?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this link might contains helpful info http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a5300fc5-126c-4e33-8ae6-13376031e9fe/how-to-lock-or-unlock-a-file-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following pattern:

1. Try to read the image (if succeeds, than done)
2. Try to create the image with Write lock
3. Only on "File in use exception", small delay (milliseconds)
4. Go back to step 1 (retry)

Make the delay really small, just a tiny bit larger than the time it should need to create an image. 
Implement a retry limit, max 3 times or so.

This would allow you to make use of the already existing (file) locking mechanism

Answer (score -1):

You can call the `open` function with `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` flags. The first process's open call will get exclusive access to create the file and it will start downloading the image. The subsequent process's open call will fail because their open is not exclusive and "errno" will be set to EEXIST.

Based on your design, the subsequent processes can either wait for complete file creation or can return back.

```
fd = open(path, O_CREAT|O_EXCL)
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm using ASP.NET

Comment: Yes! Because i've tagged my question with C# and not C.